# Merge Pandas DataFrame rows into a string in one column

Tags: python, pandas

Given this DataFrame

```
       r3  value
r1 r2           
1  2    3      1
   2    4      1
   3    2      1
   3    4      1
   4    2      1
   4    3      1
2  1    3      1
   1    4      1
   3    1      1
   3    4      1
   4    1      1
   4    3      1
```

...what's the best way to do this?

```
        r3     value
r1 r2           
1  2    3,4    2
   3    2,4    2
   4    2,3    2
2  1    3,4    2
   3    1,4    2
   4    1,3    2
```

Basically, I'm trying to condense the `r3` column into a comma delimited string. The `value` column can be achieved a different way later on if necessary, or if it can be done through this whole process, even better.

Comment: So you want to group by `(r1, r2)` with `r3` becoming the concatenation of all the individual `r3`s and `value` becoming the sum of all the individual `value`s? (Your data could make this more obvious by having differing numbers of rows grouped and by using something other than 1 for some of the values).

Comment: Yes, r3 will be a concatenation. The value figure is basically a "count" column... so it would be # of rows concatenated from the r3 column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the agg function after grouping the dataframe.  if `df` is your dataframe use this...

```
strJoin = lambda x:",".join(x.astype(str))     
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg({"r3":strJoin,"value":np.sum})
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you. As a part time, amateur coder this would have taken me a long time. Many thanks.